# How to join two table without foreignkey with refrence uf uid

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am new to DRF I have seen few solution but didnt worked in my case: I have 2 model both have same userID I want to join both table , I have tried but it didnt worked. My modal class is :

```
class UserGPSFeed(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )
    device = models.ForeignKey(
        'UserSensorDevice',
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    hardware_serial = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    fixok = models.BooleanField()

class UserSensorDevice(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    sensor_type = models.ForeignKey(
        'SensorDevice',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    pseudonym = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sensor_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My serializer class

```
class UserGPSFeedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserGPSFeed
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['id','created_at',]

class UserSensorDeviceWithParamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserGPSFeedSerializer(many=False,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserSensorDevice
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['id','created_at']
```

Views.py

```
class UserSensorDeviceParamListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSensorDeviceWithParamSerializer
    queryset = models.UserSensorDevice.objects.filter(sensor_type=2)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

I want to get all user sensor device with parameter. as both have same foreign key. So is there any way to link these type of situation. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about your goal but if you just want to include some data based on something you have in your current serializer you can try this

```
class UserSensorDeviceWithParamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_gps = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_user_gps(self, obj):
        # you can do this
        return UserGPSFeed.objects.filter(user_id=obj.user_id)
        # OR if you prefer
        return UserGPSFeed.objects.filter(user=obj.user)
        # both are the same but using user_id may give a slightly faster performance

    class Meta:
        model = models.UserSensorDevice
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['id','created_at']
```

Note that, `user_id` is the name of the column created in your model when specifying a foreign key as it holds the id for the recored it points to

**Update**: regarding error `Object of type UserGPSFeed is not JSON serializable` it means that django failed to parse the result to json automaticlly because it's not a model instance but a queryset - sorry I forgot to handle that - so we need to use a serializer to do so, to serialize every object in the returned queryset.

Luckily you have already made this serializer, so we only need to pass the returned queryset to it, so we update `get_user_gps()` to be like this,

```
def get_user_gps(self, obj):
    user_gps_queryset = UserGPSFeed.objects.filter(user_id=obj.user_id)
    user_gps_serializer = UserGPSFeedSerializer(user_gps_queryset, many=True)
    return user_gps_serializer.data
```

The first example still valid of course if it will return one object

Comment: I have tried but its not working.  I am getting an error `Object of type UserGPSFeed is not JSON serializable`

Comment: I have updated my answer regarding this error, please read it.

Comment: It turned out! My question is wrong! Anyways I have finally solved my issue. By understanding your solution. Thanks! You saved my day!

Comment: You are welcome, mate.
I may guess it was about fields in your models and .. etc, for this I recommend reading DRF tutorial https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/ it will help you a lot and give a better understaning.

anyway, I'm glad it helped, have a nice day :)